# BeautifulSoup - Help me pick out divs and classes

Tags: python, html, json, beautifulsoup

Heres my HMTL code:

```
<div class="BlockA">
    <h4>BlockA</h4>
    <div class="name">John Smith</div>
    <div class="number">2</div>
    <div class="name">Paul Peterson</div>
    <div class="number">14</div>
</div>

<div class="BlockB">
    <h4>BlockB</h4>
    <div class="name">Steve Jones</div>
    <div class="number">5</div>
</div>
```

Notice `BlockA` and `BlockB`. Both contain the same elements, ie `name` and `number` but are inside seperate classes. I'm new to python and was thinking of trying something like:

```
parsedHTML = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"name" : "number"})
```

but that just gives me a blank screen. Is it possible for me to do a `findAll` from within `blockA`, display the data, then start another loop from `BlockB` and do the same?

Thanks.

EDIT: For those asking, I want to simply loop through the values and output in JSON like this:

```
BlockA
    John Smith
    2
    Paul Peterson
    14

BlockB
    Steve Whoever
    123
    Mr Whathisface
    23
```

Comment: You have not told us what you want to do! ;-)

Comment: What do you want with attrs={"name" : "number"}???? Perhaps you want to read the BeautifulSoup carefully(!) and use {'class' : 'number'} or whatever....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find divs that contain a class attribute of "name" or "number"?

```
>>> import re
>>> soup.findAll("div", {"class":re.compile("name|number")})

[<div class="name">John Smith</div>, <div class="number">2</div>, <div class="name">Paul Peterson</div>, <div class="number">14</div>, <div class="name">Steve Jones</div>, <div class="number">5</div>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a list of possible `class` values.

```
soup.findAll('div', {'class': ['name', 'number']})
```

After seeing your edit:

```
def grab_content(heading):
    siblings = [s.contents[0] for s in heading.findNextSiblings()]
    return {heading.contents[0]: siblings}

headings = soup.findAll('h4')
[grab_content(h) for h in headings]
```

And the output for your original HTML snippet would be:

```
[{u'BlockA': [u'John Smith', u'2', u'Paul Peterson', u'14']},
 {u'BlockB': [u'Steve Jones', u'5']}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I do a `finadAll(h4)` that just returns `BlockB` when I output at the end using `return HttpResponse(h)` and `return HttpResponse(h.content)` returns none. Is there something I'm missing?